# HtmlEncoding using Razor view engine

Tags: c#, razor, html-encode

i am using Razor view engine's dll do to some templating in my code where I have some thing like Hello, @Model.name as input and my view engine would parse it. It works great but I would like it to Html Encode as well. It does not do it. For example, if I have something like "Hello  @Model.Name."

And if @Model.Name is "P & G" the I do not want output to be `hello P&G` I want output to be like `hello p &amp; G` which Razor view does not do. Is there any way to achieve this? I also tried putting HttpUtility.HtmlEncoding on top of it but that did not do the job as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Umm, what? MVC _by default_ html encodes all the output, and you have to use something like `@Html.Raw()` to get a non-encoded string.

Comment: I am sorry HttpUtility.HtmlEncode works well. I would prefer Razor solution rather than .NET library solution if possible.

Comment: Well, one thin gto note here is that I am working outside MVC environment. Just using Razor library and that's it. I actually tried @Html.Raw.....did not work.

Comment: In your base class for your email template, you have implementations for `Write` and `WriteLiteral` right? If so, you can simply inject that library call into your writes and thus gain the encoding by default on all calls.

Comment: Well, well, It turned out that I was using very old version of RazorEngine.DLL and I updated it with NuGet which gave me v3- beta and it does Html encoding by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
@Model.name is @Html.Encode("P & G")
```